# MEAN.io - install npm gives many errors

Tags: node.js, npm, mean.io

This problem is driving me absolutely insane...following all the instructions from mean.io (http://learn.mean.io/) I get to the part where i need to do npm install on my newly created project folder, and then I get loads of error messages:

```
E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean>npm install
npm WARN engine meanio@0.7.1: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x","npm":"1.4.x"}     (current:
{"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
> meanio@0.7.1 preinstall E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules
\meanio
> node ./scripts/preinstall

npm WARN engine mean-cli@0.9.26: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x","npm":"2.1.x"}     (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})

> mean-health@0.1.7 postinstall E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\mean-health
> node ./postinstall.js
|
> mean-cli@0.9.26 preinstall E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\node_modules\mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall
/
> meanio@0.7.1 postinstall E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio
> cd ./lib/core_modules/server && npm install && cd ../../..npm WARN package.json server@ No description
npm WARN package.json server@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json server@ No README data
-
> kerberos@0.0.9 install E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>node
"E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\binding.sln]

> bson@0.2.21 install E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node "E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node
-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\binding.sln]
method-override@1.0.2 node_modules\method-override
└── methods@1.0.0

gridfs-stream@0.5.3 node_modules\gridfs-stream
cookie-parser@1.3.4 node_modules\cookie-parser
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
└── cookie@0.1.2

express-validator@2.9.0 node_modules\express-validator
└── validator@3.34.0

passport@0.2.1 node_modules\passport
├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
└── pause@0.0.1

express-session@1.10.4 node_modules\express-session
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── on-headers@1.0.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── depd@1.0.0
├── crc@3.2.1
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
└── uid-safe@1.1.0 (base64-url@1.2.1, native-or-bluebird@1.1.2)

express@4.12.3 node_modules\express
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0
├── methods@1.1.1
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── vary@1.0.0
├── finalhandler@0.3.4
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── content-type@1.0.1
├── serve-static@1.9.2
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@1.0.0
├── qs@2.4.1
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
├── on-finished@2.2.0 (ee-first@1.1.0)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.7 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.9)
├── send@0.12.2 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.7.0, mime@1.3.4)
├── type-is@1.6.1 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.0.10)
└── accepts@1.2.5 (negotiator@0.5.1, mime-types@2.0.10)

connect-mongo@0.4.2 node_modules\connect-mongo
└── mongodb@1.4.35 (readable-stream@1.0.33, kerberos@0.0.9, bson@0.2.21)

> mean@0.4.3 postinstall E:\Users\Ben\Documents\web\MEAN\very Mean
> node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall

Installing Bower dependencies
Auto installing package dependencies
Dependencies installed for package articles
Dependencies installed for package system
Dependencies installed for package users
Dependencies installed for package theme
Package not found.
Package not found.
Package not found.
meanio@0.7.1 node_modules\meanio
├── complex-list@0.1.4
├── dependable-list@0.1.1
├── lazy-dependable@0.2.0
├── q@1.2.0
├── uglify-js@2.4.19 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10,     yargs@3.5.4, source-map@0.1.34)
├── glob@4.5.3 (inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.4, once@1.3.1, minimatch@2.0.4)
├── mean-health@0.1.7
├── request@2.54.0 (caseless@0.9.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.0, form-data@0.2.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, oauth-sign@0.6.0, stringstream@0.0.4, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, qs@2.4.1, node-uuid@1.4.3, mime-types@2.0.10, combined-stream@0.0.7, http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, bl@0.9.4, hawk@2.3.1, har-validator@1.5.1)
└── mean-cli@0.9.26 (opener@1.4.1, async-series@0.0.1, progress@1.1.8, commander@2.7.1, chalk@0.5.1, shelljs@0.3.0, prompt@0.2.14, json-file-plus@2.0.0, inquirer@0.8.2, bower@1.4.0, npm@2.7.4)
```

I already have .NET framework installed and visual studio. I have mongodb, node, git, bower, mean-cli, and gulp all installed.

Any ideas? 
Using Windows 7. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed the .NET framework in the default location (`C:\Program files`, if I'm not wrong)?

Comment: Yeah, it is installed in C:\Program Files(x86) by default. Just uninstalled and reinstalled .NET and get the same error.

Comment: Are you running the commands from the VS command promt (as admin)?

Comment: I've got VS 2013 Express which does not include a command prompt. I've been using the regular command prompt that comes with Windows 7 (as admin).

Comment: Its pretty hard sometimes. Just skimming through the error msgs, it looks like it requires .NET frmaework 2 sdk which is pretty old and may not be installed with vs2013. Also if you can find the vcbuild command in one of your visual studio folders, try adding that to the path.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem? I solved a similar problem a few days ago, but for that I had tried to install `mongodb` using `npm`, instead of `MEAN.IO`.

I solved my problem with this command:

```
npm install --msvs_version=2013 mongodb
```

"--msvs_version=2013" because the Visual Studio on my machine is the 2013 version.